# Is it possible to put constraints on type alias with concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

It is fairly straightforward with SFINAE:

```
using Integral = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<Foo>>;
```

I want the syntax something like:

```
#include <iterator>
using iterator = std::bidirectional_iterator ContainerIterator;
```

which is not supported.

The workaround is to use a type-checking class:

```
template <std::bidirectional_iterator T>
struct CheckContainerIterator {
  using type = T;
};

using iterator = CheckContainerIterator<ContainerIterator>::type;
```

Is there a more concise way of achieving this?

The reason being is that the SFINAE version of `bidirectional_iterator` does not seem to present in the standard. So I either have to implement it or use the type-checking class.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need such a thing?

Comment: @Barry It is for me to check if I implemented a type correctly. I know it's only useful for internal implementation.

Comment: @PHD Wouldn't a `static_assert` be better for checking for a correct implementation?

Comment: @IlCapitano `static_assert` inside the class constructor could be an option if the constraint was not `concept`.

Comment: @PHD Why not if the constraint is a `concept`? Again, it would be helpful if the question indicated the actual problem, since right now the question seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Barry Is it possible to integrate `concept` with `static_assert`?

Comment: @PHD Yes. Evaluating a `concept` gives you a `bool`. So `static_assert(std::integral<int>)`, for instance.

Comment: @Barry Oh I didn't know that. I only knew that `concept` consumes the succeeding type when used without `<>`. Thanks for the perfect suggestion.

Comment: @PHD: Where does `Foo` come from?

Comment: @NicolBolas It is just an arbitrary name. The same goes for `is_integral_v`.

Comment: @PHD: But where does the name come from? Is it meant to represent a template parameter of a template alias?

Comment: @NicolBolas `Foo` in that example is just a class. `Integral` is a normal alias declaration.

Comment: Don't edit answers into your question. Instead, you should edit your question so that it's actually clear what you're asking, so that somebody can provide an answer to it. Especially because writing `enable_if_t<std::bidirectional_iterator<It>>` is not a thing that ever makes sense to write, so I don't understand why you're writing it.